# Express + AngularJS html5mode when refreshed not working correctly

Tags: angularjs, express, html5mode

I am working on building web apps with Express and AngularJS. The problem is I though I pretty well understood how to figure out html5 mode (avoiding hashbang on url for angular apps), but I didn't.

Right now for ordinary urls such as www.url.com/register, it works perfectly fine. Even if I refresh it it stays stable just okay.
However, for some url that has parameters such as 'www.url.com/user/1231231412414', when I refresh it, I see bare json data set.

I put router.get('*', {=}) stuff at the very end of the route script, and tried anything I can do, but I am totally stuck.

Is there anybody who know the solution and had gone through this problem? I would really appreciate for any help or advice for this problem. Thanks, guys.

Comment: it sounds like you have the same URLs on the server as the client?  i.e. you have `/user/` in angular and a `router.get('/user/'...)` in node.  When the client tries to go to `/user/` they get the angular route, but when an outside connection (browser reload, direct link, etc.) hits the server, they get your api instead.  you probably should use `/api/user` on your server routes.  Failing that, posting both the server route config and angular route config will help to identify where you are going wrong.

Comment: You are right, Thank you so much. I fixed the problem by differentiating the urls in clients and server sides!